# Create C++ Class with "Default/Main" Value (ie 'string')

Tags: c++, class, winsock

so i wondering on how you create a class in c++ where the object itself has a main value like how 'string' works

for example:

```
MySocket m = SOCKET kSocket;
m.Connect(...);
SOCKET aSocket = m;
```

where m has a default type of SOCKET but has other variables and functions

Comment: What are you asking?  That code doesn't even compile (unless you make liberal assumptions, such as if SOCKET were an empty macro).

Comment: i'm asking how do i make a std::string like class that holds a value without having to call m.variable or m.getVariable()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is late.. so I am going to make a big leap here.

I think you are looking for auto type converters. There isn't a default type. What you are looking for is a way to automatically type convert a `m` into a `SOCKET`.

look up using something like

```
    class MySocket
    {
        public:
          operator SOCKET()
          {
                SOCKET socket;
                socket.handle = _handle;
                return socket;
          }
    };
```

Comment: alright, this was a good push in the right direction. thanks Andrew